# Why doesn't my Graphics card clean the cache buffer at start-up?

Tags: 11.10, ati

I have noticed a strange phenomenon when I try to reboot my Ubuntu pc. I have a multi monitor configuration with a Radeon HD6870 graphic card and when I reboot my pc I can see at the start-up of the OS the images of the application previously used!

They are only pics like a wallpaper but few instants after these images disappear.

Why does this happens?

**Updating:**
when the monitor turns on again I can see it to flicker with three horizontal bars. I have to turn the monitor off and back on in order to update the sync with the graphic card.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @EricCarvalho I have updated the question.

Comment: Does the problem remain in 12.04 or 12.10?

Comment: Yes, it remains the same.